# Checking whether two tables have identical content

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I check and store in variable whether two tables have identical content?

I have table variable with data like

```
declare @table1 table (id int)
insert into @table1 (id) values (1), (2), (3)
```

and as the second table I have query

```
select T.id from SomeTable T
inner join @table1 T1 on T.id = T1.id
```

the query returns data:

```
id
-----
1
2
```

In this case I need write false(0) into `declare @HasAccess BIT` variable.
When the query returns data:

```
id
-----
1
2
3
```

then I need write true(1) into `@HasAccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  There are various ways.

Given that you have one column, you can do:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null;
```

This checks if an `id` doesn't match in either table.

Another way uses `union all`:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select id, sum(in_t1) as num_t1, sum(in_t2) as num_t2)
      from ((select id, 1 as in_t1, 0 as in_t2 from table1) union all 
            (select id, 0, 1 from table2)
           ) tt
      group by id
     ) tt
where num_t1 <> 1 or num_t2 <> 1;
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Are there any other ways? I'm trying to use `except` but no success

Comment: Thanks, I like the first one but there are duplicates. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor . . . Actually duplicates don't matter for the query.  I was being a little overly cautious there.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (just for fun).  This will compare the entire table fields and values.

I suspect not the best option for LARGE tables

**Example**

```
Select IsIdentical = case when (Select * from Table1 Order by id For XML Raw) 
                             = (Select * from Table2 Order by id For XML Raw) 
                     then 1 else 0 end
```

> **EDIT - Option with Inner Join**

```
Select IsIdentical = case when (Select * from @Table1 Order by id For XML Raw) 
                             = (Select A.* 
                                 From SomeTable  A 
                                 Join @Table1 B on A.ID=B.ID
                                 Order By id For XML Raw) 
                     then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I need inner join. Table2  is large. I can't select all

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor Updated answer for inner join

Comment: Doesn't work when table1 = 1,2 and SomeTable = 1,2,3

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor Color me confused.  Then they are not identical,  I suspect SomeTable thousands of records not in table1.

Answer (score 0):

Using `EXCEPT`:

```
SET @HasAccess = ISNULL(
    ( SELECT 0
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT ID /* add more columns here if needed */
        FROM @table1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT ID /* add more columns here if needed */
        FROM SomeTable )), 1 )
```

### Explanation:

1. Return all `ID`s from `@table1`, except those found in `SomeTable`
2. Return 0 (false) if any records have been returned by [1].
3. If no records returned by [1] the main query will return `NULL`, hence the `ISNULL`

### Advanatages

Can easily be extended to comparisons on more than one column.